# fstat works, stat does not

Tags: c, linux, file, raspbian

I am compiling an Angband variant on Raspbian, and the following fails:

```
struct stat txt_stat, raw_stat;

/* Build the filename */
path_build(buf, 1024, ANGBAND_DIR_EDIT, template_file);

/* Access stats on text file */
if (stat(buf, &txt_stat))
{
  /* Error */
  msg_format("Oh dear, something went wrong with stat()! %s", strerror(errno));
  msg_format("Could not retrieve stats on the text file at {%s}", buf);
  return (-1);
}
```

What annoys me to no end is that the file is there at 
`~/git/hellband/lib/edit/r_info.txt`

When I replace the above code with code that opens the file (using the same buf) and then use `fstat()` on the file descriptor, it works!!

I dont want to open a file (and remember to close that file), I just want to know/fix what is going on with `stat()`.

PostScriptum 2020; it turned that when I used the Angband approach to opening files, it autoexpanded the ~ sign, which is why that worked, and fstat worked.

Comment: What error / errno are you getting?

Comment: The file or directory does not exist.

Comment: Of note to voters, my question was good enough to get the right (accepted!) answer.

Comment: Without details, the phrase about `fstat` is very confusing: the first idea about opening the file - using `open` - would suffer from the same problems about `~` as the `stat` function. Please, either provide more details about `fstat` case (that is, usage of `my_fopen` for open the file) or remove this note completely. And it is better to add the error message into the **question post** itself. In current form, it is unclear from the question post (without comments!) that `stat` fails because it cannot find the file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think you missed my point entirely, for experienced folks like P.P. this question was good enough.

Comment: @tomdemuyt: "... for experienced folks like P.P. this question was good enough." - Yes, experienced folks simply **drops** your note about `fstat` when answers. And even after your comment about `my_fopen` the respond was "But I don't know if that's what you are using.". In other words, it is clear which file contains the code you show us, but your modification "When I replace the above code with code that opens the file" is quite **vague**. Using the function `my_fopen` which is defined in the same file doesn't look like "the **standard way** everyone should use in the context of Angband".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. `stat(2)` doesn't expand or understand `~` (tilde).

You could `HOME` instead. For example, `getenv("HOME")` and then prefix it with your filename before calling `stat(2)`.

Comment: Is OP actually passing the unexpanded path to `stat`? OP mentioned getting the code to work by replacing the `stat` call with `open` (or possibly `fopen` plus `fileno`) and `fstat`, but those won't expand or understand the `~` (tilde) either!

Comment: Angband uses a `my_fopen`, perhaps it expands the tilde.

Comment: Googling Angband shows a "my_fopen" and it certainly does: http://angbandsource.wikia.com/wiki/Z-file.c But I don't know if that's what you are using. Whatever "open" you're using, it must be expanding; otherwise, I'd expect the failure for the same reason.